# "Could not find or load main class Grails" when building Grails app in Jenkins

Tags: grails, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I've installed Jenkins and had some luck getting it to run tests and deploy code, but we're starting to write all of our web apps in Grails and those are perhaps the most important of all.

It currently runs on a Windows machine, installed as a service.

I've installed the Grails plugin for Jenkins. In "Manage Jenkins/Configure System" I have JDK 1.7.0.21 configured and pointed to its install directory (the install automatically checkbox is unchecked). I have 3 versions of Grails installed on the machine, 1.3.7, 2.0.4, and 2.3.4. Each of these is configured in Jenkins, "install automatically" is unchecked, and each points to the dir that version is installed in.

In the job configuration, I select a specific grails version (2.3.4) from the dropdown, and I have non-interactive and plain output checked. The targets field is set to this value:

```
"war -Dgrails.env=ci etp"
```

When I click the "build now" button, it attempts to build the Grails app. The console output follows:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\joyler\.jenkins\jobs\Test Grails Project Automation\workspace
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git.somedomain.com/st/etp
Checking out Revision 0a909c7a6b591e65078004026624ac9e0227d6f5 (origin/master)
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\grails\grails-2.3.4\bin\grails.bat "-Dgrails.work.dir=/C:/Users/joyler/.jenkins/jobs/Test Grails Project Automation/workspace//target" war -Dgrails.env=ci etp --non-interactive --plain-output --verbose && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Error: Could not find or load main class Grails
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It's obviously seeing the Grails installation, or else it wouldn't even be able to run grails.bat.

I expected this to be a breeze, even dotnet builds were simple once I figured out where the exes were. What am I missing? Is there a good way to troubleshoot this that I'm too dumb to see?

Answer (score 1):

Try running Jenkins as admin, that solved this problem for me, it had to do with symlinks not being availlable to the user running Jenkins.

Comment: I will try this... it makes sense, I changed the user Jenkins runs as to solve another problem. Thank you for the answer.